# Why is it legal to inappropriately access privates in an explicit instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, private, language-lawyer, access-specifier

Why on earth would this be allowed:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<typename T>
struct invisible
{
    static typename T::type value;
};

template<typename T>
typename T::type invisible<T>::value;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<typename T, typename T::type P>
class construct_invisible
{
    construct_invisible(){ invisible<T>::value = P; }
    static const construct_invisible instance;
};

template<typename T, typename T::type P>
const construct_invisible<T, P> construct_invisible<T, P>::instance;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class A
{
public:
    A(int x) : m_X(x){}
private:
    int m_X;
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct A_x{ typedef int A::*type; };
template class construct_invisible<A_x, &A::m_X>;// <---- WHY DOES `&A::m_X` WORK HERE?

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    A a(17);
    std::cout << a.*invisible<A_x>::value << '\n';
}
```

<sub>Credit goes to [Johannes Schaub](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html) for the above C++ abuse. ([Demo](http://ideone.com/o9Pt5))</sub>

Are there other cases you can access what should be invisible to you? Is this just a 'bug' in the standard?

Comment: Here is [more simplified version](http://ideone.com/lNINt) of this question. On the question, I think the `private` member is used just to instantiate a type. Still, one can't create objects out of it.

Comment: @iammilind - your more simplified version does not access the value of the private member at runtime, which is kinda the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is so that the author of the class that has the private member can explicitly instantiate that member or pass it as an argument as you just did.

The compiler has no idea who is in front of the keyboard, so the access checking here is rather conservative.

Parameters used in explicit instantiation get special treatment because there is no mechanism for a class author to explicitly instantiate a template in an allowed context or to somehow permit doing so with a friend declaration.

Comment: Downvote comment? This answer is correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: This same logic applies any time private would prevent compilation. It could always be the class author at the keyboard. Why are explicit template instantiations special?

Comment: @prax the class author can put those accesses that would cause the error into an allowed context by moving it into a member of the class or by making the hungry accessor a friend. My answer is intended to be made up of the two paragraphs in conjunction. The second paragraph is not meant to be an alternative phrasing of the first. If we take both paragraphs into account, my answer doesnt anymore apply to those other cases.